# How do I auto-enable on an ssh public key login on an ASA?

Tags: cisco-asa, ssh

I am trying to allow an ssh session to auto-enable on my ASA.  I am enable to ssh to the asa with the public key and get directly to a non-enabled prompt, but I want that prompt to enter in enabled mode so that I can use the account for automation without storing passwords in a script.

Per the cisco docs, if you specify `auto-enable` on the `aaa authorization exec LOCAL` line, it should automatically put an inbound localdb user in enable mode.

Thinking that I might also need to set service-type, I set `service-type admin` on the user in question.

Relevant config:

```
aaa authentication ssh console tacacsgroup LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console tacacsgroup LOCAL
aaa authentication http console tacacsgroup LOCAL
aaa authorization command LOCAL
aaa accounting command tacacsgroup
aaa accounting enable console tacacsgroup
aaa accounting ssh console tacacsgroup
aaa authorization exec LOCAL auto-enable
```

And the user entry:

```
username redacted password redacted encrypted privilege 15
username redacted attributes
 service-type admin
 ssh authentication publickey re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed:re:da:ct:ed hashed
```

Comment: What version of ASA are you running?

Comment: Are you running at least ssh v.1.99 ideally 2.0? Can you switch on ssh debug? #debug ssh 19

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested with ASA 9.1.7 and found that telnet and ssh with password authentication works fine with "auto-enable", but ssh with publickey does not.  A workaround is to push the enable sequence to each ssh session:

```
notroot@ubuntu:/www$ ssh 10.89.168.49 $'en\n\n'
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
LABNET-CORE-ASA5510-1> en
Password: 
LABNET-CORE-ASA5510-1# <you are left here>
```

If you're industrious, open up a TAC case and ask Cisco to fix the bug.